# Getting the GHC to accept type signature with KnownNat arithmetic

Tags: haskell, math, ghc, number-theory

I have been trying to implement the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_equations_.28k_.3D_2.29), for the specific case of just two equations, using the [Data.Modular](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Modular.html) package. The idea is that I can specify each equation with only one modular number (`x = a (mod m)` using the number `a (mod m)`). Here is my implementation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy (Proxy (..))
import Data.Modular

crt :: forall k1 k2 i. (KnownNat k1, KnownNat k2, Integral i) => i `Mod` k1 -> i `Mod` k2 -> i `Mod` (k1 * k2)
crt a1 a2 = toMod $ (unMod a1)*n2*(unMod n2') + (unMod a2)*n1*(unMod n1')
  where n1 = getModulus a1 :: i
        n2 = getModulus a2 :: i
        n2' = inv $ (toMod n2 :: i `Mod` k1)
        n1' = inv $ (toMod n1 :: i `Mod` k2)

        getModulus :: forall n i j. (Integral i, Integral j, KnownNat n) => i `Mod` n -> j
        getModulus x = fromInteger $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

I get the following error: `Could not deduce (KnownNat (k1 * k2)) arising from a use of ‘toMod’`. However, shouldn't GHC be able to do the arithmetic for `KnownNat (k1 * k2)`? Also, for some weird reason, it looks like if I had a constructor for the `Mod` type instead of the `toMod` function, everything would work. I fail to see how that should make a difference either...

I am looking for any fix to help this compile, including whatever extensions. I would, however, like to not have to make my own version of Data.Modular if possible. (I think I could make this work inelegantly and clumsily by using the `Mod` constructor directly).

Comment: GHC 7.8 isn't really able to do any arithmetic _at all_, its `Nat`s are pretty much just as dumb (because, as general) as any other types. I think only 7.12 will be able to do all of that stuff quite the way you'd like. (But I think there's some plugin that gets things working even in 7.8.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise) is the plugin.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm currently at 7.10, if that helps. I've gotten some simple arithmetic with `Nat`s working before, except for this peculiar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheap, cheesy way to make this compile is to add `FlexibleContexts`, then add `KnownNat (k1 * k2)` to the context of `crt`. Once I did this, I could successfully call it in ghci:

```
> crt (3 :: Mod Integer 5) (5 :: Mod Integer 7)
33
```

Have fun working out how to express `Coprime k1 k2` as a constraint... ;-)

Comment: I don't know anything about `FlexibleContexts`, but I'll look it up, then come back and accept this answer. I hope to fully appreciate your last line joke by then. :-)

Comment: @Alec Oh, the last line has nothing to do with flexible contexts. It's just an acknowledgement that type-level programming is a notorious time sink.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I got that, just wanted to see how little `FlexibleContexts` would give me, but yeah. Thanks a lot for this solution! I have no clue how you came up with this.

Comment: @Alec "How I came up with it" is actually pretty simple: I just followed the errors. The error says it can't prove a constraint, so I gave it the constraint as an axiom; the next error said that constraint was invalid unless you turn on `FlexibleContexts`, so I turned that on. GHC did all the hard work, really.